# as3 Using split to remove the first word

Tags: actionscript-3, split

i'm trying to using split but cant really remove the first word "Wednesday"

```
Wednesday: Thundery Shower
```

any help here ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a string variable like this

```
var text:String = "Wednesday: Thundery Shower";
```

Case 1: If you want to replace the first word always then why not just find the first space index and clean the string til that point.

```
var firstSpace:int = text.indexOf(" ");

// if we have a space then remove first word.
if(firstSpace != -1)
    text = text.substr(firstSpace+1);
```

Case 2:
If you just want to remove the word "Wednesday:", then just:

```
text = text.replace("Wednesday:", "");
```

Be sure to always check the ActionScript manual and live docs, there are always samples there.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark it as resolved it if fixes your needs.